# Code not returning permutations

Tags: python, math, scope, permutation

I have written python code to permute a list of numbers.

```
class Solution:

    def __init__(self):
        self.permutations = []

    def permute_helper(self, nums, chosen):

        if nums == []:
            print chosen
            self.permutations.append(chosen)
        else:
            for num in nums:
                #choose
                chosen.append(num)
                temp = nums[:]
                temp.remove(num)

                #explore
                self.permute_helper(temp, chosen)

                #un-choose
                chosen.remove(num)

    def permute(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        self.permute_helper(nums, [])
        return self.permutations

s = Solution()
input = [1,2,3]
print s.permute(input)
```

It returns:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

I want all the permutations to appear in the returned list like this

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

I think it has something to do with scoping but I have no idea what I've done wrong to make the list returning nothing.

Comment: Does it help to know that `itertools` already has a ready-to-use `permutations` function, or is this one of those "I have to write it myself" situations?

Comment: Its one of those i have to write it myself situations. The permutation algorithm works its just that there's a scoping problem with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append `chosen` to self.permutations, any change you make to `chosen` after the fact will also affect each element of `self.permutations`. By calling `chosen.remove` later, you remove numbers from `self.permutations` as well. Consider this simpler example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b.append(a)
>>> a.remove(2)
>>> b
[[1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3]]
```

You could append a shallow copy of `chosen` to `self.permutations` instead, in which case changes made to `chosen` afterwards will have no effect on `self.permutations`.

```
    if nums == []:
        print chosen
        self.permutations.append(chosen[:])
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Shoudn't we teach `list.copy()` instead of `list[:]`? It is clearer and only a little bit slower.

Comment: @MegaIng, certainly `copy` is a good approach, provided one's version of Python supports it. I suspect the OP is still using 2.7, so I went with the older approach.